# Sylius Installation - ProductBundle is Missing

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm new in sylius development and I'm getting trouble to install some sylius bundles. I want to build a small online store and I pretend to use SyliusProductBundle, SyliusCartBundle and the required SyliusResourcesBundle.

How can I add them to my project?

Just to test, I've downloaded and installed the sylius full stack and I've noticed that the ProductBundle isn't there. I've read the documentation of both ProductBundle and CartBundle. The ProductBundle was replaced?

So, I have 2 problems:

1. Figure out what bundles should I use (I think Product and Cart but ProcuctBundle is aparently missing)
2. How to install this standalone bundles via composer.

I'm using symfony 2.3.1

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware the product bundle is still active (last commit was 7 days ago). To install and use the product bundle specifically, follow these steps from the docs:

http://docs.sylius.com/en/latest/bundles/SyliusProductBundle/installation.html

You can install any other bundle stand alone by adding the package, as found on packagist, to your composer.json file and running `composer update <packagename>`. The sylius bundles are here:

https://packagist.org/packages/sylius/

In terms of the specific bundles you'll need, there are 2 places you'll be able to learn more:

1. Documentation - covers integrating product, cart and resource bundles pretty well. The remaining bundles are WIP.
2. Sylius Demo - the [features](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/tree/master/features) and the last successful [travis build](https://travis-ci.org/Sylius/Sylius/jobs/8043287) will give you the best indication of the functionality supported by Sylius.